# ERPConnect (Theobald Software): RFC authorization

Tags: .net, saprfc, erpconnect

I want to call a remote SAP function via **ERPConnect (Theobald Software)**:

```cs
R3Connection con = new R3Connection("host", 1, "user", "pw", "EN", "700");
con.Open(false);
RFCFunction func = con.CreateFunction("FUNCTION_NAME");
```

Here I get the following exception:

> User ... has no RFC authorization for function group RFC1

Is it generally necessary to have RFC1 group authorization?

Answer (score 3):

Mybe this will help:
http://www.theobald-software.com/wiki/ERPConnect_Authority_Objects

Answer (score 0):

Yes. RFC1 and SYST are required to read information about the RFC data structures and the system infrastructure from the target system.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the authority objects for ERPConnect moved to the new Knowledgebase of Theobald Software. It can be found here now:

https://my.theobald-software.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/7/67/authority-objects

Best

Ali